# Что делает оператор исключающего ИЛИ в данном массиве?

Tags: c#

Решаю задачу, вот тут в коде метода с рекурсией есть вот такой код:

```
int currentIncrement = string.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayToSearch[^1]) ? 1 : 0;
string[] newArrayToSearch = arrayToSearch[..^1]; // что значит [..^1];
```

Про 2 точки знаю, это показывает "от начала до ..^1";
А вот оператор исключающего ИЛИ что здесь делает, как это работает?

Из высшей математики помню что исключающее ИЛИ работает так:
"Исключающее ИЛИ ложно тогда и только тогда, когда оба операнда равны True или False в одно и тоже время, во всех остальных случаях — true".

Могу предположить что в данном случае идёт сравнение объекта или индекса строки с 1...

Comment: [Индекс с конца](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes#:~:text=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%5E%20(-,%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0,-)%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)

Comment: Спасибо. Добавьте как решение, я галочку нажму

Comment: Можете написать сами ответ (если не найдете уже существующего "дубликата").

Comment: Я смотрю C# постепенно перенимает всё из питона ))

Answer (score 3):

`^ - является оператором индекса с конца`

```
// пример кода
string[] words = new string[]
{
                // index from start    index from end
    "The",      // 0                   ^9
    "quick",    // 1                   ^8
    "brown",    // 2                   ^7
    "fox",      // 3                   ^6
    "jumped",   // 4                   ^5
    "over",     // 5                   ^4
    "the",      // 6                   ^3
    "lazy",     // 7                   ^2
    "dog"       // 8                   ^1
};              // 9 (or words.Length) ^0
```

За информацию спасибо @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Это не хороший ответ, потому что он превратится в тыкву сразу как ссылка перестанет работать. Внесите минимально необходимую информацию в сам пост.